# Inductive colimits of free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is every group isomorphic to an inductive colimit (that is, directed colimit, also called inductive limit, or directed limit) of free groups?

I guess, the answer is no. In that case: Is there a characterization of the groups that are isomorphic to inductive colimits of free groups?

Comment: Directed limit often refers to inductive limit of *injective* homomorphisms. Anyway... what do you think of a group with 2 elements, in this case too?

Comment: With injective connecting homomorphisms the question will be very different. In fact, it seems to me that an inductive limit of free groups with injective connecting homomorphisms is again a free group.

Comment: No, for instance $\mathbf{Q}$ or $\mathbf{Q}\ast\mathbf{Q}$ are not free but are inductive limits of free groups with injective homomorphisms. These are not free. Inductive limits of free groups with injective homomorphisms are called "locally free groups". Another non-free example is the $\pi_1$ of the Hawaiian earring space.

Comment: Actually I think it's true (but nontrivial) that all inductive limits of free groups are locally free. This reduces to the finitely generated case, in which case it follows from the fact that any sequence of epimorphisms between finitely generated free groups stabilizes (because the rank decreases until it stabilizes, and then we have isomorphism by Hopfianness).

Comment: Every group that is a directed colimit of free groups has homological dimension at most 1 and cohomological dimension at most 2. In particular, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is not a directed colimit of free groups.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, you are right. I was not aware of "locally free groups". Also your argument that inductive limits of free groups are locally free seems like a perfect answer to me.

Comment: Again, I'm using filtering assumption. Indeed any amalgam of free groups is a (non-filtering) inductive limit of free groups. There are non-free such examples.

Comment: Yes, with inductive colimit I mean the colimit of a system of groups indexed over a directed set, for example a sequential system $G_1\to G_2\to G_3\to\ldots$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group. Equivalences:

1. $G$ is locally free (i.e., all its finitely generated subgroups are free)
2. $G$ is a filtering inductive limit of free groups with injective connecting homomorphisms
3. $G$ is a filtering inductive limit of free groups.

The equivalence between (1) and (2) is clear (given that subgroups of free groups are free - otherwise "locally free" would be a bit imprecise); (3) is tautologically implied by (2).

Conversely suppose (3), and let's prove (1). Passing to a finitely generated subgroup of $G$ reduces to $G$ finitely generated. Then passing to a cofinal subsystem allows to assume that the filtering system has an initial element $H$ with $H\to G$ surjective. Then some finitely generated subgroup $K$ of $H$ has onto image in $G$ and then replacing each group in the filtering system, we realize $G$ as a filtering inductive limit of finitely generated free groups with surjective connecting homomorphisms. Then the rank of these free groups decreases until it stabilizes, and since finitely generated free groups are Hopfian, this means that there's a cofinal subsystem made up of isomorphisms. So $G$ is free.

Note: for more other classes of groups, usually such an implication as (3)$\Rightarrow$(2) fails. For instance, every group is a filtering inductive limit of finitely presented groups (this is not specific to groups!), but usually this cannot be done with injective connecting homomorphisms (e.g., for an infinitely presented finitely generated group).